# For tensorflow 1.8, It seems I don't have to write code to reuse variable in RNNCell

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I followed the language modeling tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent and read corresponding code: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py.

I found the author coded like this from the 237th line:

```py
outputs = []
with tf.variable_scope("RNN"):
  for time_step in range(self.num_steps):
    if time_step > 0: tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
    (cell_output, state) = cell(inputs[:, time_step, :], state)
    outputs.append(cell_output)
output = tf.reshape(tf.concat(outputs, 1), [-1, config.hidden_size])
return output, state
```

I know that variables in `RNNCell` (or any other cell) are created when method `__call__` is called and the variables should be shared after the first time step. But In my experiment, I removed the line:

```py
    if time_step > 0: tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
```

and printed `tf.all_variables()` :

[image]

It seems I don't need write code to reuse variable, Am I wrong?

(I also do this experiment in tensorflow r0.12(coresponding code at: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.12/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py), if I remove that line, it will raise a

> ValueError: Variable Model/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/BasicLSTMCell/Linear/Matrix 
>   already exists, disallowed.)

Besides if I creat several `RNNCell` objects in the same varible scope, I think all of them share the same varibles, but in practice each object creats their own variables. I am really confused.